# React Native - React Native Firebase - Google Sign In Android

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native

I have a problem, I followed all of the documentations, but I still get this error :

```js
> Task :react-native-google-signin:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
/Users/galihlarasprakoso/Projects/ReactNative/RealProject/pawonku/node_modules/react-native-google-signin/android/src/main/java/co/apptailor/googlesignin/RNGoogleSigninModule.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.bridge.BaseActivityEventListener;
```

Why cannot find symbol BaseActivityEventListener?

Answer (score 1):

This often happens in newer version of React Native, due to changes in `react-native init`, try ensuring that the maven config in your project-level `build.gradle` looks like this:

`maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
}`